# Delphi 2009 not assigning events of custom components

Tags: delphi, events, event-handling, delphi-2009, custom-component

I created a custom component *TCustomHTTPReqResp* inheriting from *THTTPReqResp*.

I did also create a custom event for this component. The only problem I'm having is that although the event is published and appears on the IDE, when I assign an event handler and run the application the event handler doesn't get called.

However if assign it on the code on Form.Create i.e.:

```
CustomHTTPReqResp1.OnBeforeGet := CustomHTTPReqResp1BeforeGet;
```

it works. Apart from this everything else works just fine.

Have a done something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for the custom component:

```
unit CCustomHTTPReqResp;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Dialogs, SOAPHTTPTrans;

type
  TCustomHTTPReqResp = class(THTTPReqResp)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FOnBeforeGet: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure DoOnBeforeGet;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure SetOnBeforeGet(const AOnBeforeGet: TNotifyEvent);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(Owner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Get(Resp: TStream); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }

    { Events }
    property OnBeforeGet: TNotifyEvent read FOnBeforeGet write SetOnBeforeGet;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('My Components', [TCustomHTTPReqResp]);
end;

{ TCustomHTTPReqResp }

constructor TCustomHTTPReqResp.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);
  // Code here.
end;

destructor TCustomHTTPReqResp.Destroy;
begin
  // Code here.
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCustomHTTPReqResp.SetOnBeforeGet(const AOnBeforeGet: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  FOnBeforeGet := AOnBeforeGet;
end;

procedure TCustomHTTPReqResp.DoOnBeforeGet;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnBeforeGet) then
  begin
    FOnBeforeGet(Self);
  end
  else
  begin
    MessageDlg('No Before Post Event Handler found!', mtInformation, mbOKCancel, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomHTTPReqResp.Get(Resp: TStream);
begin
  // Raise OnBeforeGet.
  DoOnBeforeGet;
  inherited Get(Resp);
end;


end.
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code; the event is being fired (tested for sure on D2009). Just one ***off topic note*** - you don't need a setter for `FOnBeforeGet` in this case, so you can save the `SetOnBeforeGet` and use directly `property OnBeforeGet: TNotifyEvent read FOnBeforeGet write FOnBeforeGet;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments everyone, and thanks TLama for the tip.

It turns out I made a mistake on the form. I dropped the custom control on the form from the Tool Palette and also created another one on Form.Create with the same name and I think this caused the problem. Fixed now.